# Switching from portrait to landscape two different view

Tags: android, listview, galleryview, landscape-portrait

Im working on application in that I want ListView with images in portrait mode and GalleryView with same images in Landscape mode I created folder in res/layout-land/main.xml(Landscape) and normal res/layout/main.xml (portrait) but I'm getting an exception

```
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.landscape/com.landscape.ListAvtivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:210)
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at com.landscape.ListAvtivity.onCreate(ListAvtivity.java:43)
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-02 11:21:06.420: E/AndroidRuntime(775):  ... 11 more
```

and when i delete main.xml from layout-land the application works fine and displays only ListView.

Comment: check both layout listview id's are same.

Comment: can you check manifest file for checking launchmode for the activity as it might be the case onCreate is not called.  Please check and let us know the result.

Comment: @SathishBabuS: there is only 1 listView in layout/main.xml

Comment: @Roll no1: can u plz illustrate what are the changes needed in menifest

Comment: can you check if onCreate() is method is called when you are switching from landscape to portrait ?

Comment: Application crashed as soon as it runs

Comment: yes now its working fine but while ladscape only its crash hay and its  called onCreate() but crashed just before setContentView(R.layout.main);

Answer (score 2):

Add the main.xml which is in layout-land in your question.

The ListView in the layout-land/main.xml looks to not contain android:id="@android:id/list"

**EDIT**

The activity should not extend `ListActivity` but only `Activity` because it search in the contentview a listview with id `@android:id/list`.

You have to use the `ListView` manually.

Comment: my main.xml which having listview is in layout/main.xml and layout-land/main.xml consist galleryview ....... I tried both way @android:id/list also @+id/list its giving me same error and if i delete main.xml from layout-land the code works fine and shown listview

Comment: what happened if you just duplicate the layout/main.xml in layout-land ? is the app crashes too ?

Comment: I think I got it, your Activity can't extend `ListActivity` if the content view does not contain a listview with id `@android:id/list`. Set manually list content in portrait, and gallery content in landscape

Comment: yes im doing manually only like this

 Configuration c = getResources().getConfiguration();

       if(c.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ) {
         // portrait
     CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list, R.id.title, data);
   setListAdapter(adapter);
   getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

       } else if(c.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE ){
         // landscape
           Gallery ga = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);
           ga.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

       }
but still the same error in landscape

Comment: the problem is that the activity extends ListActivity. It should not. What happeans with Activity instead?